# TestNG error-java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.TestRunner.addListener(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have installed testNG version is (6.9.11).My pom .xml has (6.14.3).Eclipse version neon 4.6.3

I am getting the below error when I run the class through TestNG.Can anyone please help me on this ?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.TestRunner.addListener(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:32)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:61)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
```

Comment: If you build and execute it via the command line do you see the same issue? This will tell you if its an issue with your eclipse config or your code.

Comment: Try below solution if it does not work then provide pom.xml file

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Adding the TestNG Library into the project.

1. Right Click on the Project
2. Build Path
3. Configure Build Path
4. Libraries (Tab)
5. Go to "Add Library" and click the button.
6. Add the 'TestNG' Library and click Ok/Next.
7. TestNG Library will be added to your project.

   Restart the project

Answer (score 0):

Correct steps - working for me:

1. Right Click on the Project
2. Build Path
3. Configure Build Path
4. Libraries (Tab)
5. Go to "Add Library" and click the button.
6. Add the 'TestNG' Library and click Ok/Next.
7. TestNG Library will be added to your project.
8. Restart the project